# Solr IN Query like Sql

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 6.1, and I need to implement a search Query based on IN condition.
I have a field in Solr name "def_idc" which is String type in Solr mapping.

Now I need perform **IN** query in "def_idc" field.

Like sql refrence :

```
 select * from table where def_idc in ("ZW", "AQ", "OP")
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic Lucene syntax, with `q.op=OR` if necessary (depending on the default operator set in your schema), should do that for you:

```
def_idc:(ZW AQ OP)
```

Comment: correct. take also a look at this page, there is the full Lucene syntax wich is used by default in Solr.  https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html